# Guice missing annotations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using Guice 3.0 to build the dependency tree. I have been searching the manual  how to register types which may throw exceptions. I found this link http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders which deals exactly with this topic. The problem is, I am not able to use any of the types described on the page. I tried the interfaces `ThrowingProvider<T,E>`, `CheckedProvider<T>` and annotation `@CheckedProvides`. For all of the types listed above I get the "cannot find symbol" compilation error. The manual specifies that some of the types were added in Guice 2.0 and others in version 3.0. As I specified at the top I am using Guice 3.0. Does anybody has any idea what am I missing or maybe encountered same problems? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Uros

Comment: This tripped me up too, if you go on maven central and search for com.google.inject.extensions and see the package names of the ones you need to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which JARs are you using? The [main Guice 3.0 download page](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/detail?name=guice-3.0.zip) offers a ZIP file, which includes `guice-3.0.jar` but also feature packages like `guice-multibindings-3.0.jar` and `guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar`.

One of those feature JARs is `guice-throwingproviders-3.0.jar`, which probably isn't on your classpath yet. Adding it should help.